# Ubuntu 14.04 Installation on acer altos G520

Tags: intel-graphics, raid

I got an old server and I'm trying to install Ubuntu from USB.

Everything is fine till I selected Ubuntu Live or Ubuntu installation. The Display starts to switch between differnt resulution modes. Using nomodeset didn't help and also the option vga=769 didn't do the difference.

Help would be aprreciated, if you need more details, please feel free to ask.

Ralph

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: what flavour of Ubuntu you're running? What Graphics hardware you have?  Please [edit] your question and add this information...
Sorry for answering your question before asking this, but I wanted to ensure you didn't follow that advice for a server...

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to install a server, use the [server package](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server) and use the 14.04.2 LTS version.  That way you don't have to worry about any desktop or graphical settings, it'll be valid for 6 years **(unlike 14.10)** and you manage it remotely from an Ubuntu Desktop.